# Unable to fully package my Python script with all the modules and dependencies it needs for Linux

Tags: python, pex

I have a Python 2.7 script that uses BeautifulSoup4 and requests modules.

The issue is, that I need to deploy this script on a machine to which we can not directly install any new modules/libaries via `pip install` or anything else. 
We can copy this script and any files it needs to run to that machine, but we can not directly install any modules.

I have tried PyInstaller, PEX and Nuitka to create an executable file or a bundle (in any format, for example .zip) so that we can copy the entire file or bundle into the machine and run the python script from there, without the need to do pip install or installing the modules manually via Wheel file. All without success.

**Environment details:**
**Target machine on which the script needs to run:** RHEL-based Linux OS with Python 2.7.
**My development machine:** Windows 10 but I also have access to Fedora Linux machine both with Python 3 and Python 2.7.

The import section of my script looks like this:

`from __future__ import with_statement
from __future__ import absolute_import
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from io import open`

Can someone, please, help me out here? 
We have the script ready to be deployed, but we are not able to run it in our target machine because of the missing modules/libraries.

Thank you very much

**EDIT:**
Mentioning this since it may not be clear at first - we do not have the issue with a network connection or anything of this gender. We were prohibited to use `pip install` or a manual method of installing a module. Therefore, we can only bundle the modules directly with the script or something so that would not need to directly install the modules on the target machine itself.

Comment: your issues with installing from pip are because there is no network? you can download packages from PyPi and install them with pip locally on the other machine (just make sure you download all the requirements)

Comment: Hello Ofer Sadan, the issue is not with installing it via network, but that we can not install any Python modules because the vendor of that machine prohibited us from it because when there will be an upgrade, it could break the Python installation - and that could then void our warranty (that was his reason). So, the issue in general is, that we can not directly install any modules/libraries nor via pip install nor manually. So they need to be included directly with the script or in a script directory or something. Thank you

Comment: are you allowed to create an isolated virtual environment and install packages there? there's no reason why that would ever mess with the original python installation folder.

Comment: Well, the vendor said that we can not install any modules and that includes the `pip install virtualenv` module. So we can not use virtual environment neither. Thank you

Comment: you can manually copy all related packages to a folder of your own, and just add that folder to `sys.path` at the top of your code before importing

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I am not sure though how can I do that? Does there exist a guide on how to do that exactly? Google search did not result anything exact. Thank you

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/470982/how-to-add-a-python-module-to-syspath the first answer should be the one you are looking for.